# Phase response in MATLAB simulation doesn't match the book

Tags: simulation, control-system, matlab, bode-plot, emi-filtering

I am trying to replicate a result from a textbook that I am using to study input filter design for buck converters.
[image]

The parameters for the converter and filter are as follows:

- D = 0.5
- L = 100 μH
- C = 100 μF
- R = 3 Ω
- Lf = 330 μH
- Cf = 470 μF

The Bode plot in the textbook is shown below.
[image]

I used MATLAB to create a similar Bode response, using this code:

```
opts = bodeoptions;
opts.FreqUnits = 'Hz';

vd=5;
R=3;
D=0.5;
vo_desired=D*vd;
L=100e-6;
C=100e-6;
L_f=330e-6;
C_f=470e-6;


Gd0=vd;
w0=1/sqrt(L*C);
Q=R*sqrt(C/L);

Gvd=tf(Gd0,[1/(w0)^2,1/(Q*w0),1]);

Z=tf([L_f,0],[L_f*C_f,0,1]);
ZN=tf(-R/D^2,1);
ZD=tf([R*C*L,L,R],[C*R,1])/D^2;
Gvd_new=Gvd*((1+Z/ZN)/(1+Z/ZD));

bode(Gvd,opts,'r--')
hold on;
dcm = datacursormode;
dcm.Enable = 'on';
grid

bode(Gvd_new,opts)
legend('G_{vd}','G_{vd,new}')
```

This results in this Bode:
[image]

As you can see from the attached Bode plot I generated, the magnitude response seems to match what is shown in the textbook, but the phase response is significantly different. Am I missing something in my code or calculation?

Comment: A schematic of what the book plot represents is missing and, what your code represents has no schematic.

Comment: The only obvious, big difference between the phase plots is phase unwrapping. The textbook "unwrapped" the phase, your Matlab plot didn't.

Comment: @Andyaka apologies, the plots are for regular buck converters with an LC filter, I added the schematic.

Comment: @JRE can you elaborate more please? what do you mean by unwrapping?

Comment: The phase of the signal goes outside of -180 and 180 degrees in the textbook example.   It ranges from 0 degrees to 540 degrees. Your example forces the phase to stay between -180 and 180 degrees.  There's a discontinuity in you plot where the phase goes above 180 degrees and "wraps around" to -180 degrees.  "Phase unwrapping" is used to make the phase continuous.  [Here's how you apply it in MATLAB.](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/6340-bode-diagram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general shape of your plot appears to match that of the textbook plot.

The biggest difference that I see is that the plot you made with MATLAB has a phase wrap-around while the textbook plot has the phase "unwrapped."

The MATLAB plot is constrained to stay between -180 and 180 degrees.  That causes a discontinuity where the phase would exceed 180 degrees.

The textbook plot is continuous.  It ranges from 0 to 540 degrees.

Your MATLAB program probably has ["PhaseWrapping = 'on'"](https://de.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bodeoptions.html) set in the "bodeoptions" somewhere.  Since the default is "PhaseWrapping = 'off'", it must be your code that is turning it on.

Comment: Thank you so much, this might be an issue in the matlab version I am using, because i didn't anywhere in my code set the phase wrapping on. But that's ok fine, I just wanted to make sure I didn't make a mistake somewhere. Thanks again